# How can I combine the dateframe if the date is consecutive?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am now to python and pandas.
I have the following dateframe. I would like to combine the start and end date if they are in consecutive day.

```
data = {"Project":["A","A","A",'A',"B","B"], "Start":[dt.datetime(2020,1,1),dt.datetime(2020,1,16),dt.datetime(2020,1,31),dt.datetime(2020,7,1),dt.datetime(2020,1,31),dt.datetime(2020,2,16)],"End":[dt.datetime(2020,1,15),dt.datetime(2020,1,30),dt.datetime(2020,2,15),dt.datetime(2020,7,15),dt.datetime(2020,2,15),dt.datetime(2020,2,20)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


    Project Start       End
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-01-15
1   A       2020-01-16  2020-01-30
2   A       2020-01-31  2020-02-15
3   A       2020-07-01  2020-07-15
4   B       2020-01-31  2020-02-15
5   B       2020-02-16  2020-02-20
```

And my expected result:

```
    Project Start       End
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-02-15
1   A       2020-07-01  2020-07-15
2   B       2020-01-31  2020-02-20
```

If the next day of end is another start, I would like to combine the two rows.

Is there any pandas function can do this?

Thank a lot!

Comment: let me change the question a little bit

Answer (score 2):

Create a mask with `groupby` and `shift`, then assign the values directly and `drop_duplicates`:

```
mask = df.groupby("Project").apply(lambda d: (d["Start"].shift(-1)-d["End"]).dt.days<=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df.loc[mask, "End"]= df["End"].shift(-1)

print (df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Project","End"],keep="first"))

  Project      Start        End
0       A 2020-01-01 2020-01-30
2       A 2020-05-01 2020-05-15
3       A 2020-07-01 2020-07-15
4       B 2020-02-01 2020-02-20
```

For multiple rows instead, one way is to create an array of dates in long form by list comprehension & `pd.date_range`, and then get a mask grouped by  `cumsum`, and finally get the min/max date of each group:

```
s = [(i[0],x) for i in df.to_numpy() for x in pd.date_range(*i[1:])]
new = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s,names=["Project","Date"])).reset_index()
mask = new.groupby("Project")["Date"].diff().dt.days.gt(1).cumsum()

print (new.groupby(["Project", mask]).agg({"min","max"}))

                   Date           
                    min        max
Project Date                      
A       0    2020-01-01 2020-02-15
        1    2020-07-01 2020-07-15
B       1    2020-01-31 2020-02-20
```

Comment: Actually I am quite care about grouping by project... can i use groupby in between?

Comment: I tried the above solution. It works with two consecutive rows. But how if there are more consecutive rows?

Comment: I tried to modify the question a little bit to let you see the difference.

Comment: You really like to push it @Kilometers :) See edited.